# Can I get an .ico( Icon) to display from a local file

Tags: xhtml, icons, favicon, .ico

I am doing client side testing for my web application using IE only, there is no server - so I can test my CSS/XHTML/Javascript.

When I add the line

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon1.ico"/>
```

or

```
<link rel="icon"href="favicon1.ico"type="image/x-icon"/>
```

or

```
<link rel="shortcut icon"href="favicon1.ico"type="image/x-icon"/>
```

I do not see my .ico image displayed in the tab.

My favicon1.ico is a 32px by 32px (32 bpp, 8-bit alpha, no pallete) .ico file created/saved in GIMP residing in the same directory as my html files.

Pretty convinced IE needs a server at this point.

Comment: I'm not sure, but specifying the type attribute might work: `<link rel="icon" href="yourIcon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />`.  According to Wikipedia though, x-icon is non-standard, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28file_format%29#MIME_type

Comment: @Chris:  IMHO, you should not have edited your posting to the point where previous answers are totally invalidated.  I think amending it would have been better.

Comment: @Chris:  I edited my answer to hopefully get you running.

Comment: @Chris:  The above referenced wiki article states:  _"When using the .ICO format for (X)HTML img elements, Internet Explorer versions 6 - 9b2 cannot display files served with the correct MIME type. A workaround is to use the non-standard 'image/x-icon' MIME type."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quote OP:**  `<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="d:/bi1.ico"/>`

---

You'd simply reference all external files with **relative** urls.

If your icon file is contained in the same directory as your page...

```
href="MyIcon.ico"
```

---

**EDIT:**

This was a perfectly valid answer to the original posting.  However, the original posting has since been edited to the point where the above answer no longer makes sense.

**EDIT 2:**

The following is how mine is working.

I believe that some browsers are fussy about the name so I use `favicon.ico`.

```
<link href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" />
```

**EDIT 3:**

**Quote OP:**  *"I just saved a 40px by 40px as a .ico file"*

This does not sound right at all.  ICO files used for the Favicon are typically 16 x 16 pixels with an optional 32 x 32 pixel desktop version and/or an optional 48 x 48 pixel XP version.

[Here is an online tool for creating a proper favicon.](http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/)